# Maya FBX plugin does not support materials?

Tags: 3d, maya, mel, 3d-modelling

I am pretty new to maya, and have been trying to export my model to FBX format in order to use it in Unreal engine 4.

Problem is, whenever I export, maya gives me an error window saying "Warning: unable to export some materials", and "The plug-in does not support the following material types: Material VRayCarPaintMtl1 will be exported as a grey Lambert material" in the 'description' part of the error window.

This is really annoying and I couldn't find any solution or work around for this in the internet.
Does anyone know a solution or the cause of the problem?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Even using well-known MEL command you can export only standard Maya materials and not VRay mats:

```
FBXExportEmbeddedTextures -q;
```

For VRay materials you need a VRMat Converter instead. It allows you to export a material or a group of materials into a single .vismat file.

Look at this [Chaos Group page](https://docs.chaosgroup.com/display/VRAY3MAYA/VRmat+Material+%7C+VRayVRmatMtl)